# My SQL command isn't working

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables named user and submission. I want to natural join them. Then group them by a column. Then select two columns. Give them aliases. And then sort them by a given alias.

My code has been given below.

```
select name, count(result) as name, tried from user
natural join submission group by name sort by tried;
```

However, this isn't working. I get an error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sort by count(result) LIMIT 0, 30' at line 2

Comment: What @LightnessRacesinOrbit is trying to say is that when you say "It isn't working", there's something that lets you see that it isn't working, either the wrong output, weird behaviour or an error being displayed.  When you say "It isn't working" it helps to share all that information with us.

Comment: Use `ORDER BY` because there is no `SORT BY` syntax in SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two results with the same name:

```
select name, <-- 1st "anme"
count(result) as name, <-- 2nd name
tried from user natural join submission group by name order by tried;
```

The fix is easy as all you need to do is change the alias of the results of COUNT

```
select name, 
count(result) as result_count, 
tried from user natural join submission group by name order by tried;
```

Comment: the answer you just gave isn;t working either. It says "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from user natural join submission group by tried sort by tried LIMIT 0, 30' at line 2"

Answer (score 1):

```
select name, 
count(result) as result_count, 
tried from `user` natural join submission group by name ORDER by tried;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. But it isn't working. forget aliases. I can't even sort them. `select name, 
count(result) from user natural join submission group by name sort by count(result);` if i cut out the `sort by count(result)` part then it is working fine. Please help

Comment: @eddard.stark: At this point you would typically look up `SORT BY` in the documentation to see how you're using it wrong. In this case, you'll notice that it simply isn't there.